# ManyToMany Fields do not get filled or throws TypeError when creating an entity

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

This is a problem which I've been fighting with for a while and now I gave up. I am writing a User/Profile model in Django 2.0.2 (python 3.6 + postgres 10 on Linux) which is as follows :

```
class Config_Table(models.Model):

    entity_name = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    category = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField(blank=True,default='')
```

Above table keeps some static information which gets me into trouble.

```
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):

    "The  Profile of a user with details are stored in this model."

    username = models.TextField(primary_key=True, max_length=11)
    first_name = models.TextField(max_length=50,blank=True,default='')
    last_name = models.TextField(max_length=100,blank=True,default='')
    phone_number = models.TextField(max_length=11,blank=True,default='')
    avatar = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='Pictures/')
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M','Male'),
        ('F','Female'),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default='M')
    city = models.TextField(max_length=25, blank=True, default='NY')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=2000, blank=True, default='')
    interests = models.ManyToManyField(Config_Table, blank=True, default='')
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True)
    official_docs = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='Pictures/')
    team_name = models.TextField(blank=True,default='')
    debit_card_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    MUSIC_CHOICES = (
        ('Rock','Rock Music'),
        ('Trad','Traditional Music'),
        ('Elec','Electronic Music'),
        ('Clas','Classical Music')
    )
    favorite_music = ArrayField(models.TextField(blank=True,default=''),size=2,blank=True, default='{}')

    class Meta:
        permissions=(("User","User level permission"),
                     ("Tour","Tourleader level permission"),
                     ("Admin","Administrators"))
```

my `views.py` :

```
class UserList(APIView):
    """
    List all users, or create a new user.
    """
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        users = UserProfile.objects.all()
        target_users = []
        for user in users.iterator():
            if user.is_superuser == False:
                target_users.append(user)
        serializer = UserProfileSerializer(target_users, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = UserProfileSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save()
            print(serializer.errors)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class UserDetail(APIView):
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a User.
    """
    pk_url_kwarg = 'username'

    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return UserProfile.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        user = self.get_object(pk=pk)
        if user.is_superuser == False:
            serializer = UserProfileSerializer(user)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        user = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = UserProfileSerializer(user, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            for attr, value in serializer.validated_data.items():
                if attr == 'password' and attr is None:
                    serializer.validated_data['password'] = user.password
                    break
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        user= self.get_object(pk)
        user.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

and my `serializers.py`:

```
def create(self, validated_data):

    hashed_password = make_password(validated_data['password'])  # get the hashed password

    print(validated_data)

    user = UserProfile(
        username=validated_data['username'],
        email = validated_data['email'],
        first_name= validated_data['first_name'],
        last_name= validated_data['last_name'],
        phone_number=validated_data['phone_number'],
        avatar=validated_data.pop('avatar'),
        gender=validated_data['gender'],
        city=validated_data['city'],
        description=validated_data['description'],
        date_of_birth=validated_data.pop('date_of_birth'),
        # user_type=validated_data['user_type'],
        official_docs=validated_data.pop('official_docs'),
        team_name=validated_data['team_name'],
        debit_card_number=validated_data['debit_card_number'],
        favorite_music=validated_data['favorite_music'],
    )

    user.set_password(hashed_password)
    interest = validated_data['interests']
    user.interests.add(validated_data['interests'])
    user.groups.add(validated_data['groups'])
    user.save()

    return user
```

The problem I have happens inside the serializer, when I want to submit some JSON object through http, like below (sample data for testing) :

```
{
    "username": "12345678004",
    "password": "thisisatest",
    "last_login": null,
    "is_superuser": false,
    "email" : "sample@gmail.com",
    "first_name": "AAA",
    "last_name": "BBB",
    "phone_number": "12045678000",
    "gender": "M",
    "city": "NY",
    "description": "",
    "date_of_birth": "2010-03-28",
    "team_name": "",
    "avatar": "data:image/jpeg;base64,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",
    "official_docs": "data:image/jpeg;base64,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",
    "debit_card_number": 0,
    "favorite_music": [],
    "groups": [1],
    "user_permissions": [],
    "interests": ["Ski"]
}
```

It always returns TypeError:

```
user.interests.add(validated_data['interests'])
    Exception Type: TypeError at /users/
    Exception Value: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I have tried different ways of implementing "interests" and "groups" in the serializer create function. I tried parsing validated data, selecting the child from Config_table and adding it here, but none of them work.
I actually have the same problem with "groups" field as well. It seems that Django cannot unhash the validated data in serializer and there it throws error.

The interesting point is, if I don't fill in the "group" and "interests" field when calling the POST method, it works fine, and later, I can update those fields by calling PUT with no problem.
What can I do with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I resolved the issue like below :

I changed `Config_table` model and added default django id field (technically, just removed `primary_key` from `entity_name` row, so django added the id `AutoField` by default). Re-populated the database and changed the code in `serializers.py` like below..using the answer of @neverwalkaloner :

```
        user = UserProfile(
    ...
    )
    user.set_password(hashed_password)
    user.save()
    interests = []
    for id in validated_data['interests']:
        interests.append(id)
    user.interests.add(*interests)
    for name in validated_data['groups']:
        user.groups.add(name)
    user.save()
    return user
```

Note that **I had to save the entity before I wanted to work with a `ManyToManyField`. As django expects to see something in the database prior to adding some entities for  `ManyToMany` fields.** Keep that note in your code.

With this workaround, my problem has been resolved. But it is still strange to me why I could not use a primary key rather than the default. If anyone has an answer to this question, I'm more than willing to hear.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass to interests.add method different interests objects. Not list of names. So first you need get objects by name and then pass unpacking list of objects to add method using * syntax:

```
intersts = [] 
for name in validated_data['interests']:
   obj, created = Config_Table.objects.get_or_create(entity_name=name)
   interests.append(obj) 
user.interests.add(*interests)
```

Comment: I get DoesNotExist exception on the line which is getting the Config_table objects. I'm sure that the entity exists in the config_table and it can be inserted (as i mentioned before, I can update an existing user with interest and group)

Comment: @aLuViAn try to use get or create.

Comment: same error...maybe I need to assign id to each of the entities in Config_table and try to use ids instead of names, but it should work. Even when I print the serialized JSON in the log, I have the following:  {... 'groups': [<Group: User>], 'user_permissions': [], 'interests': [<Config_Table: Config_Table object (Ski)>]}

Comment: so django understands this is a Config_table object (Ski), but it cannot save it in the database, I'm getting really confused...BTW, can you explain what is "obj, created" mean?